# Python adding user input to SQL database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pycharm, azure-sql-database

I have been trying to add certain ices of user inputs to an SQL database(name, date, id, and description)

```
name = input("enter your name here: ")
idx = input("enter Id:")
date= datetime.date
describe = input("enter brief description: ")
```

Here is my pyodbc connect lines:

```
with pyodbc.connect('Driver=' + driver + ';SERVER=tcp:' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password) as conn:
  with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = ("Insert Into dbo.Report (Name, Date, id_number, decription)=? Values(?,?,?,?)")
    cursor.execute(sql, name, date, idx, describe)
```

but after running it I get this error:

> cursor.execute(sql, name, date, idx, describe)
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 5 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

I have entered 4 parameters (name, date[in form of datetime.date have also tried getdate() for sql], idx, and describe) what is the 5th?

Its for an Azure SQL database

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ok. hopefully that works

Comment: What is `=?` meant to be? A leftover from a previous query statement?

Comment: "certain ices of user inputs" whats an "ices"?

Comment: "ices" should be "pieces" sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have a `=?` in your query and pyodbc tries to replace it also, besides the four values, removing it will do the trick

```
with pyodbc.connect('Driver=' + driver + ';SERVER=tcp:' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password) as conn:
  with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = ("Insert Into dbo.Report (Name, Date, id_number, decription) Values(?,?,?,?)")
    cursor.execute(sql, name, date, idx, describe)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
sql = ("Insert Into dbo.Report (Name, Date, id_number, decription)=? Values(?,?,?,?,?)")
```

add a one more "?" in values.

or this

```
cursor.execute(name, date, idx, describe)
```

clear the "sql"